# App get in LocationManager approval loop

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

In my app, I have the following code;

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Start location services
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    etc...
```

Somehow, when I do a fresh install, as soon as the location manager is started, the app gets in a loop, repeating the "Do you allow this app to use Location Services"-dialog faster than I can click OK or Cancel.

The way to get out of that loop is to switch to the Settings and manually 
approve the usage.

This is iOS8, and I DID add the mandatory strings in the .plist.

What should I do?

Comment: Try moving your if block after location manager initialization

Comment: I now see that the [CLLocationManager alloc] init is called in other classes as well, in the ViewDidLoad. Likely, this is the cause. I will disable that, and get back to you.

Comment: And I will also try your suggestion Taimour. I don't have a lightning cable here, so I can only check tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could init the CLLocationManager before requesting authorisation, but I would also recommend against just assigning for permission right away. The link here has a good write up on the most effective way to ask for permission: http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/04/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are requesting permission in `applicationDidBecomeActive`  - When the permission dialog is shown your application becomes inactive (because there is a system dialog that is active) and then once the dialog is dismissed it becomes active again - but the permission has not yet been processed, so the dialog is shown and so on.

You should request location permission in another method - either `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or in your view controller or other class where you want to instantiate your `CLLocationManager` - `didBecomeActive` is not a good place to do this.

Comment: That sounds logical to me, and will give it a try tonight. Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue (not an endless loop though). Although in my case my logic needed to shift to applicationWillEnterForeground